# "etwas gegen etwas anderes eintauschen". Warum nicht 'für'?

Tags: word-choice

z.B. aus 'Ni no Kuni':

> Eine Stempelkarte gegen die "Springer"-Belohnung eintauschen?

Kann man 'für die "Springer"...' sagen?

Comment: "für" ist in dieser Verwendung **umgangssprachlich**, siehe http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fuer_statt_wegen_zuliebe (unter Beispiele 2.b.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ja, man kann beides sagen. Auf [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eintauschen) wir die Variante mit *für* als seltener bezeichnet.

Comment: Ein Königreich für ein Pferd!

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe immer ein Problem mit den "warum"-Fragen im Sprachumfeld. Auf [Wortschatz Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=208&Wort_id=2875728) kann man aber nachlesen, dass "gegen" das häufigste Wort im Zusammenhang mit "eintauschen" ist und "für" gar nicht gelistet wird. Es ist offenbar nicht falsch, wird aber trotzdem kaum verwendet.

Comment: In diesem Fall ist der Grund nicht eben rätselhaft: Anglizismus. Das Englische verwendet "exchange for", deshalb wird im Deutschen "eintauschen für" zunehmend häufig verwendet (ebenso wie "replace with" die neue Variante "ersetzen mit" statt des traditionellen "ersetzen durch" bestärkt). Unsicher ist nur, ob diese Varianten so sehr gestärkt werden, daß sie irgendwann vorherrschend werden.

Comment: @KilianFoth: Nur, dass es im Englischen die analoge Präposition verwendet wird, heißt noch nicht, dass es ein Anglizismus ist. *Für* ist im Deutschen eine durchaus gängige Präposition um Täusche auszudrücken, z. B.: »Ich gebe Dir zwei Äpfel für Deine Kinokarte.«

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Brschrft.

Comment: @KilianFoth Das ist ganz sicher kein Anglizismus! Die Verwendung von "für" in der Bedeutung "als Gegenleistung" ist schon seit dem Mittelhochdeutschen belegt. Z.B.: "die schilte wurden dar gegëbn / ze nôtpfande vür daʒ lëbn" Hartmann von Aue. (ca. 1200) *Iwein*

Comment: Um noch ein populäres und ebanfalls des Anglizismus völlig unverdächtiges Beispiel zu ergänzen: "so will ich euch wohl die Kuh für das Pferd vertauschen" in "Hans im Glück", zitiert nach http://www.maerchen.com/grimm/hans-im-glueck.php